# R close `menu` window (tcltk)? (equivalent to graphics.off for tcltk?)

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

Quick question - I'm using the `menu` function in R with `graphics=TRUE`.
For me, as I'm on linux, this results in a `tcltk` dialogue being shown. (You know how when you do `install.packages('some_package')` R pops up a window telling you to select which CRAN mirror you wish to remove? That's what I mean).

Sometimes after I make my selection (which works fine), the window then refuses to disappear or respond to any sort of clicks - I can continue my R session as normal but this window will hang around and despite my efforts to shut it down (via the close 'x' button in the corner, or via the 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons on the dialogue itself).

Is there a way I can destroy this window, given that I don't have a handle to it? **I'm looking for an equivalent of `graphics.off` for tcltk.**

Additionally, I've noted that I often get an error `[tcl] grab failed: window not viewable.` when using `menu(..,graphics=TRUE)`, so this could be related.

cheers.

Comment: By the way, this annoyance occurs reliably on my Ubuntu machine, R 2.14, but not on my Fedora machine, and these both use the tcltk interface when `graphcs=TRUE`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stuff that only happens sometimes is hard to reproduce, and is often due to bugs, and hard to figure out without a complete spec of your machine. However, I can reliably get similar behaviour and I can fix it:

```
> library(tcltk)
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
> menu(letters[1:5],graphics=TRUE)
^C
```

By hitting Control-C at this point I get my R prompt back and an unresponsive dialog box, which I don't have a handle on. Using the window manager controls on it do nothing, resizing it doesn't update the window. So...

```
> tclServiceMode(TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

then it wakes up. Then I can either close the dialog conventionally,or do:

```
> tkdestroy(".1")
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

which gets rid of it with an error I don't understand. The ".1" is the window path, which is the same as the default window title - but not if you've set a name on your menu. In which case... Ummm there's probably a way to look it up from the name, but anyway, once you've set the service mode to TRUE you can click your way back to desktop tidyness.

Comment: Diagnosis: the Tcl/Tk event loop is not being serviced. That's critical because events are how the OS/X11/WM communicate with Tk. (Technically, they send messages on a file descriptor which the “event loop” converts into dispatchable events.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! I did name my menu, but I'll certainly take what I can get with `tclServiceMode(TRUE)` and closing the window myself. I'd like to know what this `[tcl]: grab failed` thing means (I feel that this is the cause of the problem) but the circumstances under which I can reliably reproduce it are a little odd and I need to narrow them before I can ask a question here.